# doctrine: setting association with id instead of object instance

Tags: doctrine-orm

is it possible to set associations between two objects, for example `article` and `comment` like this:

```
comment.setArticle(10) // 10 is the id of article
```

autogenerated setArtcicle methods takes as argument object Article of course but maybe there are some tricks to do this?

It is very important to me from performance point of view - i would like to avoid making SQL calls always when I want to set an association. In my case there will be plenty of such unnecessary queries.

Answer (score 170, accepted):

You can use:

```
$comment->setArticle($em->getReference('Article', 10));
```

Comment: haven't seen it in "similar questions" - apologizes! thanks for the answer though! Will be accepted asap

Comment: The problem with this is when I don't have an instance of entity manager (e.g. inside of an entity). Then a more complicated solution is required.

Comment: @Czechnology it depends on what you want to do with another entity. But I don't think it's complicated.

Comment: @Czechnology You should to avoid usage entity manager in entity because of single responsibility principle.

Comment: Note you may need to do BundleName:Article