# How to set the id of a foreign key id #sf2 #doctrine2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, foreign-keys

I'm trying to manually set an foreign key id to an object, but didn't find how to do it

```
class Item
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MyBundle\Entity\ItemType", inversedBy="itemTypes")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="type_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $item_type;
}
```

Is there a way to do something link that?

```
$item = new Item();
$item->setItemTypeId(1); // This generate an error.
```

Or do i have to do like that ?

```
$item = new Item();
$type = Repository::RetrieveById(1);
$item->setItemType($type); // This generate an error.
```

Comment: You can set the relation through a Proxy Reference class
See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9308519/doctrine-setting-association-with-id-instead-of-object-instance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be done using [Reference Proxies](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/advanced-configuration.html#reference-proxies), which let you obtain a reference to an entity for which the identifier is known, without loading that entity from the database.

```
$type = $em->getReference('MyBundle\Entity\ItemType', 1);
$item->setItemType($type);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all(Do you have relation defined in ItemType Class?):

   ```
   inversedBy="item"
   ```
2. So Second:

   ```
   Repository::RetrieveById(1); // Not valid code for the repository methods
   ```
3. Replace this with:

   ```
   $type = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ACMEBundle:ItemType')->find(1);
   ```
4. And the second usage will be close to documentation.

Comment: So If I just get an Id, I have to fetch the object in DB, I cannot just set the relation without fetching the object ?

Comment: Welcome to Doctrine2 world. If you want use type_id you must write a setter and getter in entity class.

Comment: Hi, using both id & relationship was working fine till doctrine 2.2. Now both are not working together anymore... Issue with the second option is that an additional query is generated. If you already have the FK what's the need of such query? Please let me know your thoughts about that. thx