# Doctrine: use only the id to set a related entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have two entities: Product and Category. A product can be in one category, so there is a OneToMany relation between the two entities:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Category
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Product", mappedBy="category")
     */
    private $products;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->products = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getProducts(): Collection
    {
        return $this->products;
    }

    public function addProduct(Product $product): self
    {
        if (!$this->products->contains($product)) {
            $this->products[] = $product;
            $product->setCategory($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeProduct(Product $product): self
    {
        if ($this->products->contains($product)) {
            $this->products->removeElement($product);
            $product->setCategory(null);
        }
        return $this;
    }    

    // Other methods of the class 
    ...
}


/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;


    // Some properties
    ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Category", inversedBy="products")
     */
    private $category;


    public function getCategory(): ?Category
    {
        return $this->category;
    }

    public function setCategory(?Category $category): self
    {
        $this->category = $category;
        return $this;
    }

    // Other methods of the class 
    ...

}
```

With that, I can assign or remove a Category object to Product objects, which is the normal case:

```php
// set category
$categoryId = 25;
$category = $entityManager->getRepository(Category::class)->find($categoryId); 
$product->setCategory($category);
...
// remove category
$product->setCategory(null);
```

BUT, what I want to do, is that in a special an complicated situation, I have the category id (here 25), and I would like to set the corresponding category to a product, but without retrieving the Category object from the database (because it is in an entity context, where I don't want to use the EntityManager).

Is there a way to achieve something like:

```php
$categoryId = 25;
$product->setCategoryById($categoryId);


class Product
{
    public function setCategoryById(int $categoryId): self
    {
        ???
    }
}
```

It feels possible because, after all, in the database, it is just the category id which is stored in a column in the product table... but I can't figure how to do it with Doctrine.

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Try answer from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9308519/doctrine-setting-association-with-id-instead-of-object-instance), I believe it can help

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [Reference Proxies](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.9/reference/advanced-configuration.html#reference-proxies) and do something like this:

```php
$categoryId = 25;
$product->setCategory(
    $entityManager->getReference(Category::class, $categoryId)
);
$entityManager->persist($product);
$entityManager->flush();
```

Answer (score 1):

I begin with doctrine so I'm not sure of my answer ^^.

Maybe by creating an attribute that retrieves not the complete object but just the id?

Something like that:

```
   /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="category_id", type="integer")
     */
    private int $categoryId;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work... basically because the `$category` property (a Category object) is already mapped by Doctrine to a category_id column in the product table. I guess we could have a non-mapped `$categoryId` property and use it, but there is extra work to do when you persist the entity, and this is precisely what I can't figure out...

Comment: After modifying categoryId you have to save your entity and retrieve it again.

$em->persist($product);
$em->flush();

$product = "get your product"